# Angularjs ng-options selected value of dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm displaying years in adropdown list by using a custom directive.This is the template for directive.

```
template: '<select class="form-control" ng-model="joining.Year" ng-options="year for year in Years"></select>'
```

Html is like that

```
<div years-dropdown range="50"></div>
```

Years is an array of strings.Year field is of string type on my server side model.Selected value is stored correctly in the database but when I reload  the page(fetch the model from the database) I get the correct value in my controller but value is not displayed as selected in the dropdownlist.

**Edit**
One thing more when I change the selection of dropdownlist and check the html it still shows the default value as selected(first option has selected attribute). However my scope object is updated correctly.

Comment: When/Where/How do you set the year to `scope.joining.Year`?

Comment: On page load I fetch the joining object from the database and assign it to $scope.joining. joining object has a property Year .response.then(function (data) {
                                 $scope.joining= data;
                })

Comment: Can you try and change the options to `ng-options="year as year for year in Years"`

Comment: @Alon Eitan I have tried it but did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope.joining.Year` and `Years[$index]` is not the same object reference.  I don't believe `ngOptions` directive uses equivalence logic.  So this is the fix to do it manually (put this into your `.then()` function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Years.length; ++i) {
    if(angular.equals($scope.Years[i], $scope.joining.Year) {
        //the fix to get years[i] if it's equal to joining.Year
        $scope.Years[i] = $scope.joining.Year;
    }
}

//finally, apply data into joining
angular.extend($scope.joining, data);
```

Comment: KKKKKKKK I tried your answer , although it did not work but I started thinking about equality of both objects and while debugging your suggested solution it occurred to me that $scope.Years is an array of integers and my Year object is an array.It was my mistake not to give the code portion where I was populating my years array.I dont know the exact rules of marking an answer correct but your answer correctly identified the problem and lead me in the right direction.